# Why is Node.js an environment and not a platform?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment, platform

I watch this [presentation](http://introtonode.herokuapp.com/#/title) on Node where it clearly says its not a platform but an environment.

I looked up the terms environment and platforms and came across [this](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-platform-and-vs-environment/)

According to this link, Node can be considered a platform - node is neither the only way to write async apps (Python's Twisted framework) nor the only javascript environment to run server side code (meteor.js).

What is Node actually other than being a 'Event-driven I/O server-side JavaScript environment' which I totally understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That presentation, without hearing Le Zhang actually speak, says:

- Node isn't a platform or service.
- Nose is a JS environment

Both statements provide extra context than just 'environment' or 'platform' by themselves.

For example, I would consider [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to be a platform or a service that allows you to run a Python, Node.JS, Ruby or Java environment as well as number of other things.

In any case, they are both contextual terms that can be used by individuals to mean different things. Contact [the author](https://twitter.com/le_isms) and ask him what he means.